# How use a variable as a Type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'd like init a unity container based on some type from an assembly ("OneOfMyAssemblies"). I'd like register all the types (Class) inherit a specific interface ("IInjectionMarker"). I get them, I create a variable with but I can't use them as a type. The problem is on the line :

```
unityContainer.RegisterType<interfaceName, typeName> (new InjectionConstructor("MyParameter"));
```

I get the error "Can't use variable as a type". How can I solve this ?

```
var types = new List<Type>();

types.AddRange(Assembly.Load("OneOfMyAssemblies")
    .GetTypeListImplementingTheInterface(typeof(IInjectionMarker)));

types.ForEach(h =>
{
    Type typeName= Type.GetType(h.Name, true);
    Type interfaceName = Type.GetType($"I{h.Name}", true);

    unityContainer.RegisterType<interfaceName, typeName> (
        new InjectionConstructor("MyParameter"));

});
```

Comment: Have you tried `unityContainer.RegisterType(interfaceName, typeName, new InjectionConstructor("MyParameter"));`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot use types for generic methods like this.

**Option 1: using non-generic method**

After briefly checking the docs I found out that `RegisterType<TFrom, TTo>(IUnityContainer, InjectionMember[])` is just extension method of IUnityContainer and you can use one method of IUnityContainer, which is `RegisterType(Type, Type, String, ITypeLifetimeManager, InjectionMember[])`, for more details about all the parameter check the docs at [link to some unity docs](http://unitycontainer.org/api/Unity.IUnityContainer.html#Unity_IUnityContainer_RegisterType_System_Type_System_Type_System_String_Unity_Lifetime_ITypeLifetimeManager_Unity_Injection_InjectionMember___)

Should work like this:

```
Type toType = Type.GetType(h.Name, true);
Type fromType = Type.GetType($"I{h.Name}", true);

unityContainer.RegisterType(fromType, toType, null, null, new InjectionConstructor("MyParameter"));
```

**Option 2: generating generic method via reflection**

If really want to use the generic extension method I refer you to this answer, which will
show how to generate and call such method:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/5991722